# Declare in parent class and define in child

Tags: c++

So, I have class called `A` with a prototyped function x. `B`, `C`, and `D` are deriving from `A`, so the derived classes are having function x also protyped.
Now I want that not every class has function x defined. 
How is that possible in C++?

Comment: Don't declare `x` in `B`, `C` and `D`.

Comment: what do you mean by "not every class has function `x()`"? do you want `x()` not to be accessible when object `B`,`C` & `D` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to declare x as pure virtual function, e.g.:

```
virtual void x() = 0;
```

Comment: how does it answer the question?

Comment: If OP wants to run method x() by pointer to A, and (s)he don't want to supply it in every derived class, it has to be defined as virtual to silence linker error.

Comment: If you define `x()` as pure virtual in class `A` then that means you'll have to implement `x()` in all derived classes. to my understanding, this contradict his statement: *"I want that not every class has function x defined"*

Comment: @idanshmu You don't have to implement it in all derived classes. The class in which you will not implement this method will stay abstract.

Comment: indeed. anyway, I guess OP question is not clear so its hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's against the OOP principles. Inheritance means an is-a relationship. In your example, `B`, `C` and `D` are a kind of `A`. If `A` has method `x`, the others should have also.

If it's not true, `x` is not really a method of `A` (but one of it's descendants')

If `x` should be only accessible from `A` instead, make it `private`:

```
private: void x() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions about what you are asking since every class that derives from A will have x defined. If what you are asking for is that classes B, C and D are implemented in terms of A (i.e. they will utilize the functions of A but cannot be considered an instance of A), you can specify protected or private inheritance of A in B,C, and D.

Example code with this approach might be:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    public:
        void x()
        {
            std::cout << "Hello from A::x" << std::endl;
        }   
};  

class B : protected A
{
    public:
};

class C : protected A
{
    public:
    void x()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from C::x" << std::endl;
    }
};  

class D : public A
{
    public:
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //B instance_of_B;
    //instance_of_B.x(); // Will cause a compiler error 
    C instance_of_C;
    instance_of_C.x();   // Will print Hello from C::x 
    D instance_of_D;
    instance_of_D.x();   // will print Hello from A::x
}
```